# Не импортируются данные через parse_ini_file

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть две директории: /promo/sw1 и /parts (даю точные имена для удобства)

В первой лежит index.php, .ini файл с внесёнными данными, и изображение. index.php совершает include и подхватывает файл с кодом (страницу-болванку) из второй директории. В файл в директории /parts через переменную $promo я обозначаю parse_ini_file и даю ссылку на .ini файл без привязки к какой-либо директории

```
<? $promo = parse_ini_file('data.ini', true) ?>
```

И в нём же я использую данные из .ini-файла в коде

```
<? echo "<title>".$promo[знач1]." текст1 ".$promo[знач2]." текст2</title>" ?>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что ini-файл почему-то не импортируется, и ни одно значение получаемого массива не выводится

Если что, я всё делал по [этому](https://myrusakov.ru/ini-file-php.html) гайду

Answer (score 1):

Функция [parse_ini_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) пытается прочитать файл из текущего места или из include_dir.

Т.к. ваш data.ini находится в `promo/sw1`, а читать вы его пытаетесь из файла, размещенного в `/parts`, то его там нет и вы не получаете желаемого.

parse_ini_file() возвращает false при неуспешном чтении. Убедитесь в этом сами, добавьте var_dump($promo) сразу после `$promo = parse_ini_file('data.ini', true);`

Comment: Но оно выдаёт false даже когда .ini-файл находится в директории /parts

Comment: То есть с директорией так и есть (проверил и через var_dump, и через __DIR__), но оно почему-то всё равно не работает

Comment: проверьте формат ini файла и права на него. Можете приложить фрагмент файла к вопросу

Comment: Кодировка UTF-8. Права на сервере на него даны на чтение и выполнение у всех групп. Сам файл: code=sw1 | artist=Rising Eagle feat. Jahn Geor | name=Revelation (вертикальная линия - новая строка)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, моя ошибка оказалась настолько тупой, насколько это возможно

Прописывая параметры в ini-файле, я не брал значения массива после ключей в кавычки, не обозначая для php, что это обычный текст, а не ещё один кусок кода, и из-за этого текст не появлялся на странице